# How to do Nesting of Elements in XSLT for Conditional Styling?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xslt

**Question**

How can you leverage XSL to provide conditional formatting as determined by the code running (say, an increase or decrease between rows of a table)?

**Background**

**Edit:** *This is a BackgroundService implementation running using ASP.NET Core as a host for a long-running service that audits the health of an external resource. This may be a matter of .NET Core lacking some features that are present in the .NET Framework, so I figured it was worth mentioning*

This idea all started because I was looking for a way to make a simple template of HTML for which my C# data objects could be mapped to in a simple and efficient manner that didn't involve manipulating a StringBuilder. In that hope, I found [this StackOverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/897242/4271973) which said XSLT would be a great solution without having to do a full MVC approach.

Here is where it all began (abridged for brevity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>
  <xsl:template match='/Email'>
    <html>
      <head>
        <style>
          <xsl:value-of select="Styles"/>
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Total</h1>
        <table id="tblTotal" class="clsPositive">
          <tr>
            <th>Audit Date</th>
            <th>Source 1</th>
            <th>Source 2</th>
            ...
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="Total/ArrayOfElement/AuditElement">
            <xsl:sort select="ReportDate" order="descending"/>
            <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="ReportDate"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="Source1CountFormatted"/> (<xsl:value-of select="Source1GrowthFormatted"/>)</td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="Source2CountFormatted"/> (<xsl:value-of select="Source2GrowthFormatted"/>)</td>
              ...
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this, I had an idea to conditionally format the Growth-Percentage depending on the type of data represented (you can see the beginnings of this with the class attribute on the table, which I was using to identify if Increase or Decrease were Positive or Negative). However ,when I attempted to do this, Visual Studio told me the XSL was malformed:

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="Source1CountFormatted"/> (<i class="<xsl:value-of select="Source1GrowthCss"/>"><xsl:value-of select="Source1GrowthFormatted"/> </i>)</td>
```

I also tried an approach in which the "...GrowthFormatted" property would return it's inline style, but all of the HTML was immediately escaped upon parsing into an XML tree to be transformed. My last attempt before coming here was to use the xsl:text method, with disable-output-escaping:"yes". That resulted in this monstrosity of XSL (note two different approaches to see if it would work at all):

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="Source1CountFormatted"/> (<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>i class=<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&quot;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="Source1GrowthCssClass"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&quot;&gt;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="Source1GrowthFormatted"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>/i<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>)</td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="Source2CountFormatted"/> (<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;i class=&quot;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="Source2GrowthCssClass"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&quot;&gt;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="Source2GrowthFormatted"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/i&gt;</xsl:text>)</td>
```

The eagle-eyed among you may even notice that I used the textbook example provided by [Microsoft here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256107(v%3Dvs.100)#attributes) of `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>` and what, you might ask, was the result? Well, Visual Studio wasn't wrong, in that the nested elements don't work well with XSL and raised this exception:

```
XslLoadException: XSLT compile error. An error occurred at , (66, 84). ---> System.Xml.XmlException: '<', hexadecimal value 0x3C is an invalid attribute character. Line 66, poisition 84.
```

As for the extremely verbose approach, as well as the super simple approach, they both resulted in the following HTML being generated:

```
  ...
  <tr>
    <td>2019-09-19 12:30:40Z</td>
    <td>35,991,744 (&lt;i class="clsDecrease"&gt;0.00%&lt;/i&gt;)</td>
    <td>755,412 (&lt;i class="clsDecrease"&gt;0.00%&lt;/i&gt;)</td>
  ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax here is wrong:

```
<i class="<xsl:value-of select="Source1GrowthCss"/>">
```

To set a value of an attribute dynamically, you can either use `xsl:attribute` like so:

```
<i>
   <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:value-of select="Source1GrowthCss"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
</i>
```

But this is quite long-winded. The ideal approach would be to use "Attribute Value Templates", which is much cleaner

```
<i class="{Source1GrowthCss}">
```

Here, the curly braces indicate the expression is to be evaluated, rather than output literally.